# amsmath split environment results in error "Missing } inserted."

Tags: math-mode, equations, amsmath, align

The following compiles fine, but outputs a pdf with a line too long.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\def\group#1{\left ( #1 \right )}
\begin{document}

$$
%\begin{split}
 \group{\neg (v_1 = v_2) \land \neg (v_1 = v_3) \land ... \land \neg(v_1 = v_n)}
 \land \group{\neg (v_2 = v_3) \land \neg (v_2 = v_4) \land ... \land \neg(v_2 = v_n)}
 \land ... \land \group{\neg (v_{n-2} = v_{n-1}) \land \neg (v_{n-2} = v_n)} \land \group{\neg (v_{n-1} = v_n)}
%\end{split}
$$

\end{document}
```

On the other hand, I get an error when I add the split environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\def\group#1{\left ( #1 \right )}
\begin{document}

$$
\begin{split}
 \group{\neg (v_1 = v_2) \land \neg (v_1 = v_3) \land ... \land \neg(v_1 = v_n)}
 \land \group{\neg (v_2 = v_3) \land \neg (v_2 = v_4) \land ... \land \neg(v_2 = v_n)}
 \land ... \land \group{\neg (v_{n-2} = v_{n-1}) \land \neg (v_{n-2} = v_n)} \land \group{\neg (v_{n-1} = v_n)}
\end{split}
$$

\end{document}
```

Error message:

```
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.13 $
      $
```

Comment: `$$` is not supposed to be used with `amsmath` (or... at all, actually). The documentation even says as much. Try using `\[ .. \]` instead.

Comment: Oh, and `...` should be `\dotsb` because you're using `amsmath` and they are dots between binary operators.

Comment: @kahen Your comment is the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

`$$` is a low level TeX construct that has long been declared obsolete in LaTeX. Instead one should use `\[ .. \]` for displayed equations. For `amsmath` in particular, there are certain things one needs to know. (1) the `split` environment *must* be inside an `equation` or `equation*` environment, and (2) when using `amsmath`, `\[` and `\begin{equation*}` are functionally equivalent - `\[` even starts a new TeX group (not that one should rely on this, though!)

See for example ["Why is \[...\] preferable to $$?"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to). I recommend marking it as a favourite because searching for that question is near impossible.